# Hidden Markov Models methods for selecting optimal number of states

Tags: r

Package RHmm

I have a vector which I fit into a hmm model in an attemp to select an optimal number of states for a hidden markov model

```
x<-c(-0.0961421466,-0.0375458485,0.0681121271,0.0259201028,0.0016780785,0.0311860542,      
0.0067940299,0.0126520055,0.0357599812,0.0007679569,0.0409759326,0.0560839083,-0.0272581160,-0.0439501404,0.0321578353,0.0196158110,-0.0097262133,-0.0226182376,0.0119897380,-0.0099522863,-0.0359443106,-0.0039363349,-0.0476283592,-0.0383203835,-0.0518624079,0.0187455678,0.0950535435,0.0057115192,-0.0307805051,-0.0272725295,-0.0254645538,-0.0102565781,-0.0267986024,-0.0482906267,-0.0256826510,-0.0414746754,-0.0470666997,0.0284912760,0.1021992517,0.0875572274,0.0064152031,0.0200731787,-0.0091688456,-0.0575608699,-0.0442028942,-0.0277449185,-0.0115369429,0.0084710328,0.0745290085,0.0159369842,-0.0784550401,-0.0934970644,-0.0978390888,0.0160188869,0.0275268626,-0.0552651617,0.0033928140,0.0468507896,0.0374087653,0.0521167410,-0.0177752833,-0.0592673076,0.0514406681,0.0847486437,0.0738066194,-0.0098354049,-0.0572274292,0.0478305465,0.0096885221,-0.0445535022,-0.0153455265,-0.0105375508,0.0100704249,-0.0035215994,0.0243363762,0.0504443519,0.0570023276,0.0395103033,-0.0612817210,-0.0557737453,-0.0273657697,-0.0220077940,0.0083501817,0.0275081574,0.0323161331,0.0385741087,0.0175820844-0.0410599399,-0.0071019642,0.0431060115,-0.0107360128,-0.0007280372,0.0360799385,-0.0061620858  0.0164458899 -0.0050461344 -0.0578381588  0.0097198169  0.0027277926 -0.0127642317,
-0.0037062560, -0.0045482803,  0.0367596953, 0.0021176710,-0.0319243533,-0.0194663776,0.00 91915981,0.0061495737,-0.0090424506,0.0127655251,0.0161735008,0.0193814765,-0.0208605478,-0.0598025722,0.0022554035,0.0473633792,0.0247213549,-0.0063206694,-0.0201626938,0.0207952819,0.0379032576,0.0151612333,0.0038692090,0.0111271847,0.0497851603,0.0273431360,-0.0172488883,-0.0038909126,0.0264670631,-0.0065249612,-0.0467169856,-0.0255090099,0.0082489658, 0.0352569415,0.0272149172,0.0074228928,-0.0040191315,-0.0170611558,-0.0309531801,-0.0327952044,-0.0239372287,-0.0212792531,-0.0132712774,0.0086866983,-0.0007553260,0.0107026497,0.0065106253,-0.0321813990,-0.0081734233,0.0296845524,0.0268925281,-0.0025994962,-0.0038915206, -0.0126335449,0.0040244308,0.0227324065,0.0114903822,-0.0031516422,0.0031563335,0.0137143092,0.0026222849,0.0035802606,0.0111382363,-0.0008037881, -0.0282458124, 0.0056121633, 0.0254201390,0.0033781147,-0.0166139097,-0.0124559340,0.0088520417,0.0072600174, -0.0050320069,-0.0114740312,-0.0066160556, -0.0042080799, -0.0205501042,0.0027078715,  0.0122158472,-0.0206261771,-0.0267682015,-0.0107602258,0.0088477499,0.0165057256, 0.0106637013,0.0115216769,0.0278296526,0.0026376283,-0.0231543960,-0.0141964203)

#partitions test/train
nhs <- c(2,3,4) #number of possible states
S<-runif(length (x))<= .66
train<-print(S)

# mean conditional density of log probability of seeing the partial sequence of obs 
for(i in 1:length(nhs)){
pred <- vector("list", length(x))
    for(fold in 1:length(x)){
        fit <- HMMFit(x [which(train==TRUE)],dis="NORMAL",nStates=nhs[i],
        asymptCov=FALSE)
        pred[[fold]] <-  forwardBackward(fit, x[which(train==FALSE)])
   }
error[i] <- pred[[fold]]$LLH
  }
nhs[which.max(error)]    # Optimal number of hidden states (method max log-likehood)
```

Every time I run the model trying to obtain the best number of states to use of the hidden markov model I get a different number of states as I believe the model is trained over randmonly selected new values. This does not happen if I just fit the model.

```
#score proportional to probability that a sequence is generated by a given model
nhs <- c(2,3,4)
for(i in 1:length(nhs)){
    fit <- HMMFit(x, dis="NORMAL", nStates= nhs[i], asymptCov=FALSE)
    VitPath = viterbi(fit, x)
   error[i] <- fit[[3]]
}
error<-c(error) 
error[is.na(error)] <- 10000
nhs[which.min(error)]    # Optimal number of hidden states (method min AIC)
```

However results are very different. Which one is better, on one hand I have a model where I can test on new samples. On the other hand the second provides best fit on seen samples however results are very different. In case of the model if I repeat the test given that the training/test set change (random) the resulting number of states also change. In this case what percentage sample / training should I use as to be certain that this choice will provide generalization in the number of states.

What additional methods may I employ as to be able to select an optimal number of states

Many thanks

Comment: would receive better interest on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks I have also post it there.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence quantification analysis (RQA) is a method of nonlinear data analysis which quantifies the number and duration of recurrences of a dynamical system presented by its state space trajectory.

These measures can be computed in windows along the main diagonal. This allows to study their time dependence and can be used for the detection of transitions. (vertical or horizontal point = chaos-chaos transitions or diagonal structures = chaos-order or order-chaos transitions). The lengths of diagonal lines in an RP are directly related to the ratio of determinism or predictability inherent to the system.

Another possibility is to define these measures for each diagonal parallel to the main diagonal separately. This approach enables the study of time delays, unstable periodic orbits, and by applying to measures which base on diagonal structures are able to find chaos-order transitions, measures based on vertical (horizontal) structures are able to find chaos-chaos transitions, the assessment of similarities between processes.

Cross recurrence plot (CRP) will be the equivalent of cross phase analysis in wavelets. CRP is a graph which shows all those times at which a state in one dynamical system occurs simultaneously in a second dynamical system. With other words, the CRP reveals all the times when the phase space trajectory of the first system visits roughly the same area in the phase space where the phase space trajectory of the second system is. Is this last analysis which can provide a determination of the optimal number of hidden states.